# What is the "weight" of an automorphic form for $\mathrm{PGL}_2$?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms, definitions

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}$I'm trying to understand what the notion of "weight" is for automorphic forms over $\GL_2(F)$ where $F$ is some number field, in particular in connection with the Eichler-Shimura isomorphism. However I still couldn't find a source that treats all this concepts in the full generality of a number field to get precise definitions. I also feel I might be missing some key-words or misnaming some objects, for the sources I do find vary a lot in their description of what cusp forms are, though I'm sure the definitions therein are all equivalent in some sense. I'm looking for a (ideally single) reference that covers the statements numbered **(1)**-**(5)** below, or at least confirms that they are true.

Let $G$ be a reductive linear algebraic group and $\mathbb{A}$ the adèle ring of $F$. Following Piatetski-Shapiro's definition in the first *Corvalis* volume, a cusp form for $G(F)$ is a smooth function $f\colon G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}) \to \mathbb{C}$ on which the center $C = Z(G(\mathbb{A}))$ acts through a character $\omega\colon C \to \mathbb{C}^\times$, the coefficients $|f(g)|$ are square integrable over $CG(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A})$ and have vanishing integral over $U(F)\backslash U(\mathbb{A})$ where $U$ denotes the unipotent radical of any parabolic subgroup of $G$.

The smoothness condition means that $f$ can be thought of as a function $\Gamma\backslash G(\mathbb{A}_\infty) = \Gamma\backslash G(F\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{C}$ where $\Gamma$ is some congruence subgroup of $G(\mathcal{O}_F)$, and is from this connection that we recover the classical theory of modular forms from the automorphic case for $G = \PGL_2$. Thus, given any central character $\omega$ and congruence subgroup of $G(\mathcal{O}_F)$ or, which amounts to the same, a compact open subgroup $K_f$ of the finite àdelic part $G(\mathbb{A}^\infty)$, one defines the subspace $S(K_f,\omega)$ of the space of all cusps forms to be the set of all cusp forms constant on the cosets of $G(F)\backslash G(\mathbb{A}) /K_f$. In comparison with the modular case, $K_f$ plays the role of the "level" of the modular function.

Now assume $G = \PGL_n$ for some $n$, so that $\omega$ is trivial. As an "admissible representation" of $G(\mathbb{A})$, which really means a compatible representation of $G(K_\nu)$ for all finite places $\nu$ and a $(\mathfrak{g}_\nu, K_\nu)$-module for all infinite places $\nu$, we get a decomposition of $S(K_f)$ as a direct sum of closed irreducible subspaces, each isotypical component having multiplicity exactly one and being a *bona fide* real Lie representation $\pi$ of $G(A_\infty)$. The $\pi$'s that apear in this decomposition are called the *irreducible automorphic cuspidal* representations of $G(A_\infty)$.

> If I understand correctly, this representations are usually *not* finite-dimensional **(1)**.
>
> However, apparently there is a unique finite-dimensional Lie representation $\rho = \rho(\pi)$ of $G(A_\infty)$ that induce the same infinitesimal character on center of the universal enveloping algebra $U(\mathfrak{g}_\infty) = \bigotimes_{\nu\text{ infinite}} U(\mathfrak{g}_\nu)$ **(2)**.
>
> And for $G = \PGL_2$, just so happens that this representation $\rho$ is exactly the tensor product of $\operatorname{Sym}^{\lambda_\nu} \mathbb{R}^2$ for $\nu$ a real place and $\operatorname{Sym}^{\lambda_\nu} \mathbb{C}^2 \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \overline{\operatorname{Sym}^{\lambda_\nu} \mathbb{C}^2}$ for $\nu$ a complex place **(3)**.
>
> Hence, in the $G = \PGL_2$ case, the family of parameters $\lambda = (\lambda_\nu)$ describe completely the decomposition of $S(K_f)$ into irreducibles, and if $f \in S(K_f)$ lies in the isotypical factor $\pi$ whose associated $\rho$ has parameters $\lambda$, we say $f$ has weight $\lambda$ **(4)**.
>
> Let's denote the space of cusps forms of weight $\lambda$ by $S_\lambda(K_f)$. If $\Gamma$ is the congruence subgroup defined by $K_f$ and $F$ has $r_1$ real embeddings and $r_2$ conjugate pairs of complex embeddings, a consequence of the Eichler-Shimura is an equality of dimensions $$\dim_{\mathbb{C}} H^{r_1+r_2}_{\text{cusp}}(\Gamma, \rho) = 2^{r_1}\dim_{\mathbb{C}} S_{\lambda}(K_f)\,,$$ where the *cuspidal* cohomology on the left is intersection of the kernels of the restriction maps $\Gamma \to \Gamma\cap U(\mathbb{A}_\infty)$, where $U$ is again the unipotent radical of the parabolic subgroups of $G$ **(5)**.

Comment: Without reading your question in detail, the weight of $\pi$ is however the authors choose to describe the archimedean representation $\pi_\infty$.  E.g., for a holomorphic Hilbert eigenform, $\pi_\infty$ is a discrete series representation parametrized by a tuple of integers, the classical weight $(k_1, \dots, k_n)$.

Comment: @Kimball I see, so what I should search for is something along the lines of "classification of irreducible automorphic representations" of $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\operatorname{PGL}_2(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: Well, "automorphic" is only for global representations.  Try smooth or admissible.  Yyou might start by looking at the books of Gelbart (less detailed) or Bump (more detailed), which discuss the global and local pictures.